# Does not setting DbType of SqlDbType affect performance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I don't really seem to be able to find a clear answer on this. When creating parameters for an IDbCommand object, does not setting DbType or if using SqlParameters SqlDbType, have any affect on performance? I'd imagine that in most cases the answer would be no but I'm thinking specifically for high volume environments where milliseconds count.

Comment: Compared with the random amounts of latency that the network and I/O on the server are likely to incur, it's probably not ever going to be noticable. And if you thought it was the potential bottleneck for your application's performance, the usual advice would apply - actually profile it both ways and try to *measure* it with *your* code and *your* data/access patterns.

Comment: DbType? Unlikely, because the heuristics is on a completely different time scale, and it will tend to be the same on each call (except for null values). However, not setting a size of a `varchar` for example used to require a separate execution plan for each of the query variants. So you make a query with a 5-char string and the execution plan can't be reused for a query with a 6-char string. This can cause some issues with memory and CPU use of the DB server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if milliseconds count, yes. It will affect performance. That is because a couple of extra CPU clock cycles will have to be used now to determine the type. It might only take 1 millisecond to accomplish it.

It will be the same when I ask you a question; Will it affect your performance when I give you a telephone book and a name to find the correct person. You will have to test each possible. I'm not saying that this is how it is handled, I'm just making a point.

I personally thinks that the amount of time it takes is so minute that you probably won't notice the difference.